# How is INDEX on Composite Primary Key in mysql?

Tags: mysql, index, primary-key

When making a composite primary key for two or more columns, e.g. `PRIMARY KEY(col1, col2, col3)`; will the system `INDEX` each column individually?

The reason that I am asking this question is that when we use `UNIQUE INDEX (col1, col2, col3)`, it acts as `INDEX` for the first column only, and we need to create additional `INDEX`s for other columns. I want to know if that's the case for Composite Primary Key too.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. The composite primary index will always ensure that the combination of col1, col2, col3 values are unique. If the purpose of the index is to ensure that the values are unique then you will have achieved that
2. A composite index also provides for index matches on any combination of the columns col1, col2, and col3
3. You would create separate indexes on col2, and col3, if you join or filter using any of the columns without the others.
4. I always prefer a numeric primary key (with no business association), and unique indexes over a composite primary key where necessary.

Comment: +1 for these points, especially for point #2 in the event queries have GROUP BY clauses & ORDER BY clauses that need different compound index combinations.

Comment: good points! then, composite primary key is similar to UNIQUE INDEX, and we do not have index for 2nd, 3rd, ... columns for quick fetching a row?

Comment: @ssmusoke Can I assume from the omission of `col1` in point 3 that a `SELECT * WHERE col1 = 10` would be efficient?

Comment: @Andy #3 is in addition to a composite index of col1, col2, and col3 so the composite index will be used. However if you do filters on col2, and col3 without col1 then you need separate indexes for each of them alone

Comment: @ssmusoke Sorry I couldn't quite tell whether the answer was a yes or not! I understand that #3 is in addition to the composite key, and I understand that if I want to filter by col2 or col3 I'd need to index them. What I want to know is does a composite key on (col1, col2, col3) make `SELECT * WHERE col1 = 10` efficient (or should I _also_ have an index on col1?). My understanding of your point 3 was that the composite key means you don't need to index col1: is that right? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Having an index on col1, col2, and col3 means that SELECT * FROM col1 = 10 will be efficient, since col1 is the first column in the index, so #3 allows you to do the same for col2 and col3, so that if you filter by those columns alone without col1 then the columns are also indexed

Comment: @ssmusoke Just what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: +1 for 2.  only place i've found an answer for partially `SELECT`ing on a composite `PRIMARY` and your note re the omission of `col1`.  should be added to answer

Comment: I would love to upvote the answer but I disagree with point 4. Using a composite key can make in so many ways sense.

Comment: @PaulWasilewski yes indeed there are special cases where a composite primary key makes sense, but those are just special cases.

Comment: Also, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048154/indexes-and-multi-column-primary-keys. I think a very important information about the sequence of columns in the composite-key is obscured in this post. We need to index separately only when the sub-tuple is not a prefix the original ordered-tuple. Thus, no need for additional indexing when a sub-tuple is a prefix of the original tuple (composite key).